# Encased in or just encased?

Tags: word-usage

I need help, I'm writing something and I'm having trouble figuring out if encased should have an "in" in front of it or if it should just be "encased" Here's the sentence:

*Her cerulean eyes looked into mine, fear encased in them.*

How should encased be used?

Comment: Is the fear encasing the eyes or are the eyes encasing the fear?

Comment: @HotLicks
I don't know. I'm trying to relay that she was scared and that there was fear in her eyes.

Comment: Well, if you don't understand the metaphor you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @HotLicks

That's why I'm ASKING.  I wanted help, not an unhelpful remark.

Comment: If you want it to mean that there is fear in her eyes then *encased in* would be correct use of the word *encased*, but it sounds odd because the fear isn't limited to *only* her eyes, surely she's feeling the fear in her mind/soul/spirit/pit of her stomach/etc. and expressing that through her eyes.

Comment: The fear is not _enclosed_ in her eyes, is it? _Encased_ means _contained in, as in a case_.

Comment: @nnnnnn
I love you (not . . . romantically, of course) thank you for explaining! Any idea's as to how I should phrase that?